# How to display the input on JFrame from jOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I have this code.

```
String input;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type words:");
```

How do I display the input in `JFrame` if this code is inside my `mouseListener`?

I did not use `System.out.println()` because it only prints in the console.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6):

How about [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

```
String input;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type words:");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input);
```

---

If you really need it to be shown on a new `JFrame`, you can create a new `JFrame` and add `input` to `JLabel`;

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Title");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(100,100);
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(input));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Wait, where do you suggest I put this? Main? Constructor or another method? Cos I don't know how to make it work. I have a Main, a Constructor, a method where I put all the JFrames, and a couple of mousemotionlisters.

Comment: @alicedimarco You write: "How do I display the input in JFrame if this code is inside my mouseListener?" Maybe it's better to put this in the  event related to your mouseListener.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'll consider it.